# OpenGL Model Class requirements

Tags: opengl, 3d, modeling

I've been wondering this for a while when loading in your mesh and textures and whatnot in your model class, what do you keep? I figure once the vertices are passed with glBufferData() I don't need them anymore, since the call to glDrawArrays() depends on the last glBindBuffer() This is all my Model class keeps after the loadModel() method is called.

```
GLuint vboID;//for... something
GLuint vaoID;//for  glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
GLuint textureID;//for glBindTexture(GL_TEXTRUE2D, textureID);
GLuint vboElementCount;//for glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,vboElementCount);
```

From what I can tell that would be all I need to render a model. Other then that what else should I keep for a simple model?

Edit: Before someone mentions position rotation scale and what have you, I have a ModelInstance class that contains the matrices for those, and I pass it a pointer to the Model object so I can have multiple instances of the same Model.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "keep?" In Direct3D it is common practice to keep some resources handy (or at least enough information to know how to re-load them) when the device context is lost (e.g. the computer is put to sleep and VRAM loses all of its data). OpenGL makes this completely transparent, so in *theory* once you send image data to a texture, vertex data to a VBO, shader strings to a program, you can eliminate the backing resource store in system memory... some algorithms do transform on the CPU and GPU (e.g. shadow volumes), and in these cases you would need 2 copies of vertex data

Comment: By 'Keep' I meant in system memory, I keep the ID's so I can access them later but in the case of losing device context, I have honestly never considered it. Something ill definitely keep in mind. As for transforms shadow volumes are one thing, but I also realized I have no way of moving the vertices once i've passed them to VRAM unless I use the shader to move them with like a uniform mat4, or call glTranslatef() before glDrawArrays()... things I'll have to rethink or that could get messy... You make a lot of good points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I keep

- VBO ids, so I can delete VBOs when I no longer need them.
- VAO id, so I can bind before drawing and delete eventually.
- Number of indices to pass to `glDrawElements()`
- ids of all required textures.
- Material and transformation properties (uniforms in general).

This works fine as long as meshes are static. As soon as you want to manipulate your meshes on the CPU, for example smoothen or split them, you have to keep a copy in main memory. 
Maybe you also want to keep a low resolution placeholder, for example for more specialized rendering techniques like [occlusion culling](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/software-occlusion-culling). But again, this is a special case; your question lists everything needed for basic rendering

**Note:** you should think about switching to `glDrawElements()`. It will reduce the amount of vertex data you have to store and transfer.

Comment: I have been reading about glDrawElements(), the only reason I haven't used it is because the source for a basic textured cube rendering I was reading used glDrawArrays(), I'm improving on that source by adding a model class that will probably be my next change. One more small question, if I load my model with normals, do I also keep that in the vbo?

Comment: Yes, basic vertex attributes are: positions, normals, and texture coordinates. You will need more attributes if you do things like skeletal animation.